# How to limit a scoreboard team to have 1 player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make teams that have a limit of 1 entity on them, for example, a game of hide and seek, where there is 1 seeker and 5 hiders. I need to have some of the teams in my world to have a limit of 1, somewhat incorporating a random selection process to select random players to place them on teams.

Comment: Why can’t you just... assign one player to be seeker and then assign all the others to the hider team?

Comment: because im using a random scoreboard selector and through random chance they might all be hider or seeker. also im NOT doing hide and seek

Comment: The random selector only selects one person. What kind of weird thing are you using? Even if it didn’t, you could just set a limit of 1.

Comment: but HOW do u set a limit of 1?

Comment: well what selector are you using in the first place? Can you put it exactly as I don't quite understand why you are having problems

Comment: Are you using `@r` as your random selection? If not, what are you using?

Comment: If you think it's necessary to state you're explicitly "NOT doing hide and seek", it might be clearer to write down (an example closer to) what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 1):

There are no team properties to control limits, but what you *can* do is change your command setup to make sure that no more than one entity is assigned to each team.

Assuming you are using `@r` to select random players, let's try this:

```
/scoreboard teams join seeker @r
```

This command will add a random player to the seeker team. *Now, just don't run that command again, and the seeker team will only have 1 player!*

Now let's add everyone else as hiders:

```
/scoreboard teams join hiders @a[team=!seeker]
```